# How to redirect print and stdout to a pipe and read it from parent process?

Tags: python, pipe, stdout, sys

If possible I would like to not use `subProcess.popen`. The reason I want to capture the stdout of the process started by the child is because I need to save the output of the child in a variable to display it back later. However I have yet to find a way to do so anywhere. I also need to activate multiple programs without necessarily closing the one that's active. I also need to be controlling the child process whit the parent process.

I'm launching a subprocess like this

```
listProgram = ["./perroquet.py"]
listOutput = ["","",""]
tubePerroquet = os.pipe()
pipeMain = os.pipe()
pipeAge = os.pipe()
pipeSavoir = os.pipe()
pid = os.fork()
process = 1
if pid == 0:
    os.close(pipePerroquet[1])
    os.dup2(pipePerroquet[0],0)
    sys.stdout = os.fdopen(tubeMain[1], 'w')
    os.execvp("./perroquet.py", listProgram)
```

Now as you can see I'm launching the program with `os.execvp` and using `os.dup2()` to redirect the stdout of the child. However I'm not sure of what I've done in the code and want to know of the correct way to redirect stdout with `os.dup2` and then be able to read it in the parent process.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: So what you have doesn't work? In what way?

Comment: Why can't you use subprocess?

Comment: Because of the nature of the program I need to execute anything(including commands) and unless I misunderstood how `subProcess.popen` works, executing a command and a program requires different formating

Answer (score 0):

I cannot understand why you do not want to use the excellent subprocess module that could save you a lot of boiler plate code (and as much error possibilities ...). Anyway, I assume `perroquet.py` is a python script, not an executable progam. Shell know how to find the correct interpretor for scripts, but `exec` family are low-level functions that expect a *real* executable program.

You should at least have something like :

```
listProgram = [ "python", "./perroquet.py","",""]
...
    os.execvp("python", listProgram)
```

But I'd rather use :

```
prog = subprocess.Popen(("python", "./perroquet.py", "", ""), stdout = PIPE)
```

or even as you are already in python import it and directly call the functions from there.

EDIT :

It looks thart what you really want is :

- user gives you a command (can be almost anything)
- [ you validate that the command is safe ] - unsure if you intend to do it but you should ...
- you make the shell execute the command and get its output - you may want to read stderr too and control exit code

You should try something like

```
while True:
    cmd = raw_input("commande :") # input with Python 3
    if cmd.strip().lower() == exit: break
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    out, err = proc.communicate()
    code = proc.returncode
    print("OUT", out, "ERR", err, "CODE", code)
```

It is absolutely unsafe, since this code executes any command as the underlying shell would do (include `rm -rf *`, `rd /s/q .`, ...), but it gives you the output, the output and the return code of the command, and it can be used is a loop. The only limitation is that as you use a different shell for each command, you cannot use commands that change shell environment - they will be executed but will have no effect.

Comment: I don't want to use `subProcess.Popen` because I need to execute anything including terminal commands all of which I will be getting from the user which means I can't call subprocess. However if there is a way to call `subProcess.popen` and format it with a list or any other way to format a string I'd love to know it. Thank you for your help

Comment: The problem is that since I need to be able to keep starting programs without closing the current one wont the pipes just send the output to all off the activated programs? (I know the necessity of starting multiple programs was not in my original question I will correct it right away)

Comment: I didn't think of the fact that you can't pass a variable through a pipe therefore this solution doesn't work for me. Thanks for taking time out of your day to help me

Comment: What do you mean by *passing a variable through a pipe* ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution if you need to extract any changes to the environment

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import os    

def execute_and_get_env(cmd, initial_env=None):
    if initial_env is None:
        initial_env = os.environ

    r_fd, w_fd = os.pipe()
    write_env = "; env >&{}".format(w_fd)

    p = Popen(cmd + write_env, shell=True, env=initial_env, pass_fds=[w_fd], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    output, error = p.communicate()

    # this will cause problems if the environment gets very large as 
    # writing to the pipe will hang because it gets full and we only
    # read from the pipe when the process is over
    os.close(w_fd)
    with open(r_fd) as f:
        env = dict(line[:-1].split("=", 1) for line in f)

    return output, error, env

export_cmd = "export my_var='hello world'"
echo_cmd = "echo $my_var"

out, err, env = execute_and_get_env(export_cmd)
out, err, env = execute_and_get_env(echo_cmd, env)

print(out)
```

Comment: Thats a great answer and I think I have a solution to empty the pipe. Since I will be initiating the process in the child I'll send the `p` variable through the pipe so I'll be able to constantly read from the pipe

Comment: @IIIlII47IIIlII I'm not really sure what you mean. But I'm glad you have a solution to your problem.